# "Inner size" of a Control

Tags: vb.net, controls

In vb.net, what's the property of a Control to get the "inner size"? I mean the size that the control should have to doesn't display the scrollbars.
I would like to resize a form following this criteria:

-If the inner size is too small, use the default form size.

-If the inner size is between a given range, resize the form to make the scrollbars disappear.

-If the inner size is too large, set a max size for the form and maintain the scrollbars.

I'm using a [Devexpress LayoutControl](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraLayoutLayoutControltopic). 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `ClientSize` property of the control (my emphasis).

> The client area of a control is the bounds of the control, **minus the
>   nonclient elements such as scroll bars, borders, title bars, and
>   menus**. The SetClientSizeCore method is called to set the ClientSize
>   property. The ClientSize property is not always changed through its
>   set method so you should override the SetClientSizeCore method to
>   ensure that your code is executed when the ClientSize property is set.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.clientsize%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
With ClientSize I get a size that is bigger than the effective needed size. So I get an empty space at the bottom of the control. I'm using a [Devexpress LayoutControl](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraLayoutLayoutControltopic).

Comment: Anyway, I suppose ClientSize is not what I need. From the description I understand that the ClientSize is the bounds of the control, so if the size in the form is 200x300 pixels and I have a vertical scrollbar, the size I get is something like 180x300. I don't need this. If the vertical scrollbar shows 150 additional pixels I want to get a size of 200x450 pixels... Clear as mud...

Comment: In the comment above I was talking about the PreferredSize! This property sometimes gives an height that's too big and sometimes it is too short!

Comment: But you are the only one that answered my question, so I'll accept your answer!